# Split an spliti are deprecated in Php 5.3. How can I replace them?

Tags: php, split, php-5.4

I'm implementing a function that converts float numbers to strings.

```
function exp2int($exp) {
    list($mantissa, $exponent) = spliti("e", $exp);
    if($exponent=='') return $exp;
    list($int, $dec) = split("\.", $mantissa);
    bcscale (abs($exponent - strlen($dec)));
    return bcmul($mantissa, bcpow("10", $exponent));
}
```

This is an example:

```
$n = 2.777777778e-10;
echo exp2int($n);
```

Returns:

```
0.0000000002777777778
```

My server is running Php 5.4, and since **split** and **spliti** are deprecated since Php 5.3, I get these messages:

```
Deprecated: Function spliti() is deprecated
Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated
```

How can I replace those functions in my **exp2int** function (without the use of @)? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the PHP website on [split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) states:

> Tip split() is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0. preg_split() is the suggested alternative to this function. If you don't require the power of regular expressions, it is faster to use explode(), which doesn't incur the overhead of the regular expression engine.

Similarly for [spliti()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spliti.php):

> Tip spliti() is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0. preg_split() with the i (PCRE_CASELESS) modifier is the suggested alternative.

Note, however, that `explode()` takes a delimiter `string` rather than a `regex` pattern as an argument.

Comment: i tried that, but replacing split with explode does not return the exact amount of decimals.

Comment: What do you get instead?

Comment: for the same example I get: 0.0000000002

Comment: That's because you probably use `split("\.", $mantissa)`. However, `explode()` requires only the delimiter, not a pattern. Use `split(".", $mantissa)` instead.